# how to upload linkr button

Tags: joomla1.5

when I install plg.linkr_button.upgrade-any-to-2.3.7.zip & uplad file it gives error Install plugin error & this message

/home/abc/tmp/install_4d0239a35bd0f/plg.linkr_button/linkr_button.php to /home/abc/plugins/editors-xtd/linkr_button.php

OR when I upload super installer directly then it gives this error

Warning: LinkrInstaller::require_once(/home/abc/administrator/components/com_linkr/defines.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/abc/administrator/components/com_linkr/install.linkr.php on line 207

Fatal error: LinkrInstaller::require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/abc/administrator/components/com_linkr/defines.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/abc/administrator/components/com_linkr/install.linkr.php on line 207

Answer (score 0):

Either the update is meesed up or you do not have permission to read the uploaded file.